# Stub mongoDB with hapijs

Tags: mongodb, testing, sinon, hapi.js

I'm trying to figure out how to stub `mongoDB` in `hapi js` to allow testing but I have no idea how to do it. I've tried checking out `Sinonjs` but I have no idea how to apply it in this particular case.
Here's some of the code:

```
// index.js
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const MongoJS = require('mongojs');

const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ host: 'localhost', port: 11001 });

server.app.db = MongoJS('crunchbase', ['companies']);

server.register([
  {
    register: require('./lib/plugins')
  },
  {
    register: require('./lib/modules/companies'),
    options: {
      baseUrl: '/v1/companies'
    }
  }
], (err) => {

  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    server.log('info', `Server listening on ${server.info.uri}`);
  });
});

module.exports = server;
```

Here's are the routes:

```
// companies.js
'use strict';

const Boom = require('boom');
const Joi = require('joi');

const error = Joi.object().keys({
  statusCode: Joi.number(),
  error: Joi.string(),
  message: Joi.string()
});

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  _id: Joi.object(),
  permalink: Joi.string(),
  name: Joi.string(),
  homepage_url: Joi.string(),
  category_list: Joi.string(),
  funding_total_usd: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.number(), Joi.string()),
  status: Joi.string(),
  country_code: Joi.string().allow(''),
  state_code: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).allow(''),
  region: Joi.string().allow(''),
  city: Joi.string().allow(''),
  funding_rounds: Joi.number(),
  founded_at: Joi.string().allow(''),
  first_funding_at: Joi.string(),
  last_funding_at: Joi.string()
});

exports.register = (server, options, next) => {

  const db = server.app.db;
  const { baseUrl } = options;

  server.route([
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: baseUrl,
      config: {
        description: 'companies',
        notes: 'Get a list of companies from the database',
        tags: ['api'],
        validate: {
          query: {
            limit: Joi.number().min(1).max(20).default(5)
          }
        },
        response: {
          status: {
            200: Joi.array().items(schema),
            400: error,
            500: error
          }
        }
      },
      handler: (request, reply) => {

        db.companies.find().limit(request.query.limit, (err, docs) => {

          if (err) {
            return reply(Boom.wrap(err, 'Internal MongoDB error.'));
          }
          reply(docs);
        });
      }
    }
  ]);

  return next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
  pkg: require('./package.json')
};
```

And here's the test suite:

```
// companies.test.js
'use strict';

const Code = require('code');
const Lab = require('lab');

const lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
const { describe, it } = lab;
const expect = Code.expect;

const Server = require('../../');

describe('Companies module test suite', () => {

  const baseUrl = '/v1/companies';

  it('should return array of 5 companies by default', (done) => {

    Server.inject({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl
    }, (response) => {

      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      expect(response.result).to.be.an.array().and.have.length(5);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should return array of 3 companies', (done) => {

    Server.inject({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl + '?limit=3'
    }, (response) => {

      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      expect(response.result).to.be.an.array().and.have.length(3);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should throw an error', (done) => {

    Server.inject({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl + '?limit=me'
    }, (response) => {

      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(400);
      expect(response.result.error).to.equal('Bad Request');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

It works but only if there's a connection to the db which I want to decouple. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution courtesy of [devinivy](https://github.com/devinivy)

> One approach I've taken is to place queries in server methods, then
>   stub out the server methods `(server.methods.x = stubX)` in my tests.

You could also check out [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) as suggested by [timcosta](https://github.com/timcosta)

Here's the brief [github discussion](https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/557)